# 3d-plot PolyCollection - only keep top edge

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polygon

I'm trying to plot 2D-data into a 3d-plot. I came up with following plot:

[image]

I'm quite happy home it came out.
I would like to eliminate all edges but the top one and keep the (sur)faces at the same time, as the tope line is the only real representation of the underlying data. unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a straight forward solution, at least I couldn't find one yet. Is it even possible using that method?

I reached this plot by using following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection


facecolors = ['firebrick', 'lightgrey',  'goldenrod', 'cadetblue' ] 
edgecolors = ['darkred', 'darkgrey',  'darkgoldenrod', 'teal' ] 

poly = PolyCollection(data, facecolors = facecolors, edgecolors = edgecolors, linewidths=(7))
poly.set_alpha(0.7)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')

zs = range(len(data))
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 210)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, len(data))
ax.set_zlim3d(80, 200)

plt.show()
```

the data is taken from a json file and pre-processed as 'add_collection3d()' wants a collection of closed polygons;

```
    # each polygon needs a base and won't generate it automatically.
    # So for each subplot, add a base at ymin.
    if line_at_zero:
        zeroline = ymin -10
    else:
        zeroline = ymin - 10
    for p in verts:
        p.insert(0, (p[0][0], zeroline))
        p.append((p[-1][0], zeroline))
```

**Update**
as suggested in the comments, I first plotted the lines themselves and afterwards the surfaces without edges, which works fine, but produces a glitchy reult. The overlapping parts are not presented in a correct manner. thats why I still wonder if there might be a solution to just not plot specific edges within the polygon
[image]

Comment: Plot the PolyCollection with facecolor and a separate line plot with edgecolor?

Comment: Thank you!! That is of course a viable solution that I didn't think of. I tried that, but unfortunately it leaves me with glitchy results. I have updated my post. you can see that there.

Comment: Matplotlib has known problems in 3D to correctly establish the order of objects. If you need it just to create a graph without interactivity, then you could set the `zorder` manually to ensure that lines and surfaces are displayed in the correct order.

Comment: thank you so much!! works perfectly fine. I just need one perspective :)

Comment: Glad we could sort this problem out. Good luck with your project.